# PHP Mail - MIME Composition

Tags: php, mime-types, mime

I have written some code which generates and sends an email with attachment. It works fine when viewing in hotmail but in Outlook the html portion is messed up. It also seems to be adding the html portion as an attachment in outlook? Can anyone see anything wrong with the MIME below:

```
X-Mailer: PHP/5.2.0-8+etch16 MIME-version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/mixed;  
boundary="=====25ac73ba0275de9f6675bba3f3960608" From: Paul 

--=====25ac73ba0275de9f6675bba3f3960608 Content-Type: text/plain 
Content-Transfer- Encoding: 8bit   Test email: domain: test.co.uk 
name: Paul email: test@test.co.uk address: 123 tel: 123 
enquiry: 123 PAGE SENT FROM: http://test.co.uk/index.html 
--=====25ac73ba0275de9f6675bba3f3960608 
Content-Type: text/html Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 
Test email  




<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" link="#AAAAAA">

<div align="center">
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" 
width="550" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" 
style="border: 3px solid #555555;">
<tr>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;
    <!--<img src="" alt="" border="0" style="margin: 10px 0px;" />--></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif;"size="2"><strong><center>Test Message:</center>
</strong></font></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html> 



--=====25ac73ba0275de9f6675bba3f3960608 
Content-Type: application/msword; name="Test.doc" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Test.doc" 
0M8R4KGxGuEAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA Shortened 
--=====25ac73ba0275de9f6675bba3f3960608--
```

Comment: Please provide the actual HTML in addition to the headers.  Outlook 2007+ renders with the Word rendering engine, which doesn't follow HTML standards.  Such common styles as float, width, and padding aren't supported, which could easily invalidate or destroy your html layout.

Comment: When i dont add an attachment though the html renders fine...

Answer (score 0):

The headers would appear to be messed up. They should each be on a separate line. You've got:

```
Content-Type: text/html Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 
Test email
```

and they should be

```
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 

Test email
```

with a line break to separate the header section from the content section ('Test email').

Comment: they are - this was just copied from a browser dump. Is there an easy way of printing the email to a text file showing all of the line breaks etc that i define i nPHP?

Comment: Not via 'lookout'. That it can email at all is a miracle. Try using SwiftMailer or PHPMailer to generate the mail. They can spit out what they'd be mailing as a string. Generating your own MIME mail is far too much work when they can do it in only a few simple function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're interested in using some one's mail class, but here is a work in progress. It only supports php's mail() function at the moment, but its being developed for smtp. Very easy to use, and it supports attachments of course.

http://code.google.com/p/intervademailer